# Как обработать ошибку соединения с интернетом в rxJava?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Используется `rxJava2` и `retrofit2`.

```
   public Observable<xxx> go(){
  return Rest.getNews(date)              
            .observeOn(DatabaseScheduler.get())                
            .flatMap(//Тут абсолютно неважный код)
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap(//Тут абсолютно неважный код);
   }}
```

Так вот, метод `getNews` обращается к серверу, и если нет интернета, либо сервер не доступен, то вываливается ошибка и крашится приложение. Вопрос как поймать ошибку и обработать ее в `subscribe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Rest.getNews(date)              
            .observeOn(DatabaseScheduler.get())                
            .flatMap(//Тут абсолютно неважный код)
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap(//Тут абсолютно неважный код);
            .subscribe(
                (result) -> { /* Все хорошо */ },
                (throwable) -> { /* Обрабатываем ошибку */ });
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, теперь все заработало.